# Massive performance degradation rendering menus with submenus

Tags: zend-framework, menu, profiling, execution

Whenever I render a menu item, for each of the menu item I found from the database, I use it to check its sub-menus.

My Controller rendering the menu item and recursive function to detect its sub-menus are as follows

```
public function renderAction()
{
    $menu = $this -> _request -> getParam('menu');
    $itemArray = $this -> getSubItems($menu);
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($itemArray);
    $this -> view -> navigation() -> setContainer($container);          
}

private function getSubItems($menu, $parent = 0) {
    $mapperMenuItem = new Apanel_Model_Mapper_MenuItem();
    $menuItems = $mapperMenuItem -> getItemsByMenu($menu, $parent);
    if(count($menuItems) > 0) {
        $itemArray = array();
        foreach($menuItems as $item) {
            $label = $item -> label;
            $uri = $this -> getSubItemUrl($item);               
            $subItems = $this -> getSubItems($menu, $item -> id);           
            if(count($subItems)) {              
                $tArray['pages'] = $subItems;
            }
            $tArray['label'] = $label;
            $tArray['uri'] = $uri;
            $itemArray[] = $tArray;
            unset($tArray);
        }
        if(count($itemArray)) {
            return $itemArray; 
        } else {
            return null;
        }       
    } else {
        return null;
    }       
}

   private function getSubItemUrl($item) {

        if(!empty($item -> link)) {
            $uri = $item -> link;                       
        } else {
            $pageMapper = new Apanel_Model_Mapper_Page();

            $details = $pageMapper -> getPageDetails($item -> page_id);             
            $pageClass = "CMS_Content_Item_".ucwords($details['namespace']);
            $page = new $pageClass($item -> page_id);
            $title = str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($details['name']));
            $uri = $this -> view -> url(array(
                "namespace" => $details['namespace'],
                "title"     => $title
            ),'page-view');
        }
        return $uri;            
    }
```

And function getItemsByMenu in MenuItem Mapper

```
public function getItemsByMenu($menuId, $parent = 0)    {
    $select = $this -> getDbTable() -> select();        
    $select -> where("menu_id = ?", $menuId)
            -> where("parent = ?", $parent)
            -> order("position");
    $items = $this -> getDbTable() -> fetchAll($select);
    if($items -> count() > 0) {
        return $items;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have about 4 different types of menu rendered in my app and I am noticing significant performance degradation in the execution. I often get Execution timeouts, the difference between the rendering time with the menus are about 35 sec and without are 22 sec approx. And this all in localhost. Is there any flaw in my recursion? What measure can I take to improve the performance of the code?

Comment: Can you post the code for getItemsByMenu and getSubItemUrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything in there that would explain 35 second execution time, unless you have 100,000s of items in your menus table with no indexes at all. Suggestions:

1. Make sure you have an index on the menu items table on: `menu_id, parent, position` (that's one index on three fields, with the fields in that order.
2. I assume `getPageDetails` is doing another database query. Ideally you'd want to load these details when you load the menu items (by joining in the pages table), so you could then just pass the array of page data to `getPageDetails` instead of having to do an additional query per item.

If that doesn't give any miraculous improvements, try enabling the DB profiler so you can see whether it's volume or speed of the database queries that is causing the issue.

Comment: As per your first point. I do have an index as primary key in that table, if you are referring to that. And about your second point, how to do execute a custom query with a join on it?

Comment: If you only have a primary key index then you definitely need to add an additional index as per my first suggestion - this should help a lot. As for custom joins, you can use `joinInner` on the select object to pull in an extra table, although this can be a bit funky with Zend_Db_Table so try the indexes first.

Comment: I haven't worked with indexes before.... Can you please elaborate your first example with an possible example. I did setup index with index type `index` on each of those fields.

Comment: Run this as a one-off: `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD INDEX  menuParentPosition (menu_id,  parent,  position )` replacing 'yourtable' with the database table name. That will create the index I suggested, so see if you see any improvement after that.

Comment: Applied all your recommendation, now the DOM completes loading at 10 sec and rendering completes in about 15 sec. That's quite a difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem here is the way you fetch your menu from the database.

If for each menu item you do a request to fetch it's submenus, you will quickly end with *a lot* of requests. An easy solution would be to implement caching, but you could first try to improve the way you query your menu.

A good alternative for mapping trees, instead of referencing the parent item is to use a [materialized path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_path). This means that you store in a field a string containing the path to the current item, comma-separated. The real benefit is that you could get a whole tree in only one request using a regexp on the path field :

```
//get the whole tree of menu 1
SELECT * FROM menuitems WHERE path REGEXP '^1' ORDER BY path;

| ID | Name           | Path   |
| 1  | Hardware       | "1"    |
| 2  | Printers       | "1,1"  |
| 3  | Laser printers | "1,1,1"|
| 4  | Ink printers   | "1,1,2"|
| 5  | Screens        | "1,2"  |
| 6  | Flat Screens   | "1,2,1"|
| 7  | Touch Screens  | "1,2,1"|
```

Then with a little code, like some recursive function you build your whole navigation.

And consider caching this sort of things

Comment: The link you provided does not contain any article.

Comment: yeah sorry, the only resource that is not related to any techno. Here you [have an explanation for mongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-MaterializedPaths%28FullPathinEachNode%29), but it's the same principle. The difference is that the path is not related to the rows IDs